# How do I write extensions for dreamweaver cs4? What limitations are there on what extensions can do?

Tags: php, ide, dreamweaver, cs4

I use dreamweaver cs4 as my main php coding editor.  I am wondering if anyone has any information on how exactly to write a dreamweaver extension?  Also, what can / can't you do ?

Specifically, I want to write an extension that will allow me to quickly search my file tree and then open a file, via a quick auto complete search box located somewhere on the UI.  Does anyone know if this is something that could be accomplished, or how I might go about doing this?

Note also that the file tree I am referring to is the *remote* file tree, so the extension would either have to create an index or access dreamweaver's remote index (i'm pretty sure dw keeps one..)

I don't really want to switch IDEs as I have about a dozen computers at various locations all configured with dw, so can't really afford the adjustment time right now.  I'm looking specifically for how to do this in dreamweaver cs4.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I rememeber correctly older versions of Dreamweaver allowed you to write extensions in a Javascript like syntax.

[Docs on extending Dreamweaver are here.](http://www.adobe.com/support/dreamweaver/extend.html)

Comment: I had checked that link out, but none of the references seemed to be for any dreamweaver in the CS series.  The latest I saw was 8, which was quite a different dreamweaver.  Resources seem very out of date.